# regex python find dollar amount and few words at the same time

Tags: python, regex, search, text

I need to find dollar amount and few(3 or 4) words surrounding that amount at the same time in one paragraph.

```
in-process research and development of $184.3 million and charges $120 of 
million for the impairment of long-lived assets. See Notes 2, 16 and21 to the 
Consolidated Financial Statements. Income from continuingoperations for the       
fiscal year ended September 30, 2001 also includes a netgain on sale of 
businesses and investments of $276.6 million and a net gainon the sale of 
common shares of a subsidiary of $64.1 million.
```

What I want to get is something like below,
 [amount, amount+ digit words, 3-4 words after to before amount].

```
[$184.3 $184.3 million, research and development of $184.3 million],[$120, $120 of million,charges $120 of 
million for the impairment of long-lived assets ], [$276.6, $276.6 million, investments of $276.6 million] ,[ $64.1, $64.1 million,  a subsidiary of $64.1 million.]
```

What I tried is this and it only found dollar amount.

```
[\$]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2}
```

Thanks!

Comment: One you found the dollar amount, you could use its index and string slicing to find words around that

Comment: want you want as output I don't think is necessary possible with just regex, this is close: `([^\s]+\sand\s[^\s]+\s)?([^\s]+\s)([\$]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2})([\w\s]*illion)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's name the pattern you have:

```
amount_patt = r"[\$]{1}[\d,]+\.?\d{0,2}"
```

Digit word should be then defined using the above:

```
digit_word_patt = amount_patt + r" (\w+)"
```

Now, for the surrounding 3-4 words, do the following:

```
words_patt = r"(\S+ ){3, 4}" + amount_patt + r"(\S+ ){3, 4}"
```

You're done! Now simply use these with your `re` methods for your string extraction.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask one more thing? I just released that the dollar amount is not just hundreds but it also contains over thousands. How can I find all hundreds and thousands at the same time?

Comment: Aren't thousand-figures showing up with the current pattern?

Comment: Yes, that paragraph was one specific example , but actual file has a lot of paragraphs contains something like this, "$1,005.6 million pre-tax" so I want to extract amount contains comma!

Comment: @MMM Oh I got it! I've modified the answer to include that. Have a look.